# After migration, impossible to logging from the remote server, error 'You are not authorized to access this page"

Tags: 8, users, migrations, .htaccess

(Drupal 8)
From my local environment, I haven't any problem about logging with the admin user.

But after a migration from my local to my remote server, when I log with any  user (and admin), I'm redirected to the user page (/user/x, x as number) but I get this error message:

> You are not authorized to access this page
>
> [image]

If I refresh the page, I'm automatically redirected to the user login page. 
I don't understand why.

From my database, I see the new session when I logging. And the watchdog shows only the used connecting and then the access denied.

```
$drush wd-show

25136  27/Dec 00:18  access denied   warning   /user/1
25135  27/Dec 00:18  user            notice    Session opened for okli
```

Someone can help me?

I noticed I haven't any cookies in my browser after logging in. Maybe the issue is this, but I'm not an expert in Drupal login session.

During the migration, I changed the server configuration. Before, the website used a SSL certificate; I removed the certificate (and the website is in http). I don't think, but may the new server configuration is the source of the problem.

**UPDATE : my steps and log**

1) From the database, I truncate sessions and flood tables

2) I use firefox browser, I empty all registered cookies

3) I open /var/log/apache2/access.log, /var/log/apache2/error.log and /var/log/mysql/error.log with 'tail -f' from shells and I go to the loggin page with firefox (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)

[image]

4) I enter my admin name and password, then I submit my loggin form. I go to the access denied page :

[image]

5) My logs files display :

[image]

6) My cookie in my browser have this value :

[image]

7) My table session have one entry :

[image]

Is is normal my cookie value and database entry aren't the same ? 
How can/must I do for debug the loggin process and, I hope, find where is the bug ?

below, the content of my apache2.conf file :

```
Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel debug

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

    LimitRequestBody 204800
    FileETag None
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
        Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
        Header edit Set-Cookie ^(.*)$ $1;HttpOnly;Secure
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/1\.1$
    RewriteRule .* - [F]

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options -FollowSymLinks -Includes -ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
```

And my /ect/apache2/sites-enabled/xxx.conf files (there is only one conf file) :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  
    DocumentRoot /var/www/drupalmaindir

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/drupalmaindir>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My drupal watchdog :

[image]

I don't find where is my mistake and why I can't connect to my drupal website... :/

**Note**: During the migration, I changed the apache website configuration. Before, the website used a ssl certificate (https), now I remove the certificate (and the website is in http).

Comment: Did you rebuild the cache? You can do this without logging in: `www.newsite.com/rebuild.php`. To get access put this option in settings.php: `$settings['rebuild_access'] = TRUE;`

Comment: I tried add this options , and then I clear cache with drush cr. But the issue is the same, I can't connect to my website :/

Comment: The error in the last watchdog log, about the route with a missing path, do you have this in the old site, when you clear the cache?

Comment: Yes I have this notice a long time ago...

Comment: Hmmm I checked, I haven't this error in my local server..

Comment: Now, when I connect to my site, I have only the "Session opened" watchdog message, I d'ont understand hahaha. And I'am always automatically disconnected

Comment: This is only when you clear the cache. This error can be a sign, that the files are not 100 % identical on both servers.

Comment: I think its a difference between my local/remote databases. I only copy the directory all and theme to the remote server. Ill check with import the local database to the remote

Comment: Hmmm before the save and dump database, I seen I have the undefined index error in my local server. I forgotten clear caches !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to **kingfisher64** in ["Access denied" "you are not authorized to access this page" error ???](https://www.drupal.org/node/4657#comment-9405207)

> Just in case somebody stumbles over this issue the solution for me was
>   in **settings.php**. I had copied a website from one domain to another and
>   had not changed the following setting at the bottom of the file.
>
> ```
> $cookie_domain = 'newwebsitenamehere.com';
> ```

**Note:** notice how it does not have `http://` nor `www.` so **do not** put these.

---

**Update**: OPer commented:

> During the migration, I changed the apache website configuration.
>   Before, the website used a ssl certificate (https), now I remove the
>   certificat (and the website is in http).

Also, another thing to look for in **settings.php** is the `$base_url` **if it is uncommented** (does not have a # at the start) make sure it is the correct domain name (assuming you already pointed your domain name to this new server. If this server does not have a domain name pointing to it, then comment this line out) and also remove the `s` if it has https:// (since you are not using SSL).

Ex:

[image]

OR since there is no SSL, you could just comment it out, by adding a `#`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer =) but there isn't cookie_domain attribute in the setting files of drupal 8. Should I add it?

Comment: During the migration, I changed the apache website configuration. Before, the website used a ssl certificate (https), now I remove the certificat (and the website is in http). I don't think, but may the new apache configuration is the source of the problem ?

Comment: @user2137454 edit your .htaccess file and remove the HTTPS parts.

Comment: I checked, my htaccess is the same as the default (via vimdiff)

Comment: @user2137454, see my updated answer. I forgot to mention that there was another thing to look out for in settings.php

Comment: @user2137454 You might also want to check the [`$settings['trusted_host_patterns']`](https://www.drupal.org/node/2410395). No idea if that triggers such an error, but my own Drupal just reminded me of this :)

Comment: you couldn't login with any user?